# c# Converting from one object to another without using foreach

Tags: c#

I am return an student object from my database and I want to convert it into a StudentRecoredRequest model. The way i have implement is shown below. I was wondering if there was a nicer way to convert from the student object to studentsystemrecordrequest. Thanks

```
        var result = await _context.Student.ToListAsync();
        var studentInfo = new List<StudentSystemRecordRequest>();
        foreach(var student in result)
        {
            var stud = new StudentSystemRecordRequest
            {
                FirstName = student.FirstName,
                LastName = student.SurName,
                DateOfBirth = student.DateOfBirth,
                Address = student.Address1
            };
            studentInfo.Add(stud);
        }
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it provides no context. It already has 4 votes to close out of the necessary 5.

Comment: Apologies I didn't realize it provides no context.

Comment: Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Have the spelling checked, too.)

Comment: If you could provide the rest of the function, or better, the entire class that would make the question on-topic.

Comment: What exactly is off-topic about it? The linked guidelines don't say anything about requiring context, only that providing _more_ context will lead to a better review. OP asked for a review of a simple self-contained mechanism that converts one thing to another, and apparently at least three people felt there was enough content for a quality review. And you seem to agree as well given your comments and up-votes! So why vote to close?

Comment: @JeffE The class StudentSystemRecordRequest is not defined within the question for one thing. There has been a long discussion about this question in the 2nd Monitor chat room.

Comment: @JeffE Personally I link to [missing context](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652) it's a little confusing as this would be under _stub code's_ meaning but doesn't share a name. If you feel that the comments and chat have been unsatisfactory than you may get a clearer answer on Meta.

Comment: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3192900/how-to-work-with-automapper-in-csharp.html

Comment: Automapper would reduce this to 1 line. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) syntax:

```
var studentInfo = 
    (from student in result
     select new StudentSystemRecordRequest
        {
            FirstName = student.FirstName,
            LastName = student.SurName,
            DateOfBirth = student.DateOfBirth,
            Address = student.Address1
        }
    ).ToList();
```

If you are happy with `IEnumerable` instead of `List`, you can omit `ToList()`, but keep in mind that in that case the resulting enumerable will be lazy, which means that the elements will be created only when the result is enumerated. But since `result` is probably a list, which is strict, it should not be a problem.

Comment: I did up vote your answer because it is a good one, however, this question is off-topic because it does not have context. Off-topic questions should not be answered. Please consider your actions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with collections, it would be difficult to avoid loops. However, I can think of 3 possible ways that would help you convert objects back and forth without repeating the code.

The first one is to add a constructor to `StudentRecoredRequest` that accepts `Student` object.

Example :

```
public class StudentRecoredRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime DateOfBirth   { get; set; }
    
    public string Address    { get; set; }
    
    public StudentRecoredRequest() { }
    
    public StudentRecoredRequest(Student student)
    {
        FirstName = student.FirstName;
        LastName = student.SurName;
        DateOfBirth = student.DateOfBirth;
        Address = student.Address1;     
    }               
}
```

with this, you would be able to pass Student object directly :

```
var studentInfo = new StudentRecoredRequest(stud);
```

And you can add more methods to handle the conversion or add more options. Another advantage is that you can define an implicit operator on the class to cast Student into StudentRecoredRequest something like :

```
public class StudentRecoredRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime DateOfBirth   { get; set; }
    
    public string Address    { get; set; }
    
    public StudentRecoredRequest() { }
    
    public StudentRecoredRequest(Student student)
    {
        FirstName = student.FirstName;
        LastName = student.SurName;
        DateOfBirth = student.DateOfBirth;
        Address = student.Address1;     
    }
    
    public static implicit operator StudentRecoredRequest(Student student) => new StudentRecoredRequest(student);   
}
```

which would give you this :

```
var studentInfo = (StudentRecoredRequest) stud;
```

the second way is to use extensions, something like this :

```
public static IEnumerable<StudentRecoredRequest> ToStudentRecoredRequest(this IEnumerable<Student> students)
{
    foreach(var stud in students)
    {
        yield return new StudentSystemRecordRequest
        {
            FirstName = student.FirstName,
            LastName = student.SurName,
            DateOfBirth = student.DateOfBirth,
            Address = student.Address1
        };
    }
}
```

usage :

```
var studentInfo = result.ToStudentRecoredRequest();
```

The third way is to use [**Data Transfer Object (DTO)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object) This DTO would make things easier for transfer data between objects, you could use this pattern to link two objects for easier maintainability and extensibility.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is a red herring; the important bit is how you're doing the conversion from one student-ish type to another. I'd start there by writing a converter method:

```
private static StudentSystemRecordRequest ToRecordRequest(Student student)
{
    return new StudentSystemRecordRequest
    {
        FirstName = student.FirstName,
        LastName = student.SurName,
        DateOfBirth = student.DateOfBirth,
        Address = student.Address1
    };
}
```

I've chosen not to make this a member method of either of the `Student` types because I don't want to introduce any unnecessary coupling.

Such a method will compose well with LINQ, if you really want to get rid of the `foreach`:

```
var studentInfo = result.Select(ToRecordRequest).ToList();
```